# How to Verify ID Tokens with Firebase 9 on React?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

**How to Verify ID Tokens with Firebase 9 on React?**

*import*

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import firebaseConfig from "./firebase.config";
import { getAuth, signInWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
```

*.js file*

```
const storeAuthToken = () => {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true)
      .then(function (idToken) {
        // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
        // ...
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        // Handle error
      });
  };
```

*package.json*

```
"firebase": "^9.6.3"
```

Comment: The same function exists in v9 here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#getidtoken Did you try making that work yet?

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen.